# String used for a file name has escape character "\". How do I get around this?

Tags: java, escaping, filenames, character

```
PrintWriter out = 
 new PrintWriter("C:\Users\Slerig\Desktop\gnuplot\binary\cannonballOutput.txt");
```

This is my sample code. It is quite simple. It throws a "Invalid Escape Character" error because of the backslashes. How do I get around this? Programming in Java btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to escape `\` with `\\` in your string (or use `/` instead)
Use

```
PrintWriter out = 
 new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Slerig\\Desktop\\gnuplot\\binary\\cannonballOutput.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks much. I appreciate it. I literally figured it out right after I asked the question. :/ But thanks a lot. :P

Comment: "Literally" figured it out!  Is there a community wiki for SO puns?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `/` and Java will convert them automatically if you don't want to litter your paths with `\\`.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final File f = new File("C:/tmp");
        for (String s : f.list())
        {
            System.out.println("filename = " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To escape a `\` you just need to use `\\` so:

```
new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Slerig\\Desktop\\gnuplot\\binary\\cannonballOutput.txt");
```